# calinski-hrabasz f index for hierarchical clustering

Tags: r, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering

How do I compute the calinski-hrabasz f index in R for hierarchical clustering? I need it to determine the optimal amounts of clusters.

Answer (score 0):

R Package FPC might be the way to go.

```
calinhara(x,clustering,cn=max(clustering))
```

Description
Calinski-Harabasz index for estimating the number of clusters, based on an observations/variablesmatrix
here. A distance based version is available through cluster.stats.